# How to format a mysql datetime yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, date, datetime

My python code retrieves a datetime column from a mySql server database. I can print the datetime as it is stored on the server (ex. 2018-10-22, however I need to print it in a more readable way like 22-10-2018. Basically, row[0] holds datetime data as the code below. Thanks for any help.

```
if mycursor.rowcount > 0:

print("Total rows are:  ", len(myresult))
for row in myresult:
  print("Record Number: " + str(countLines))
  print("-----------------")
  print("Time: ", row[0])
  print("Latitude: ", row[1])
  print("Longitude: ", row[2])
  print("Accuracy: ", row[3])
  print("Place: ", row[4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `time` is a `datetime` object you can use `strftime()`

```
from datetime import datetime

row[0].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Output

```
t = datetime(2018, 10, 22)
t.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

#'22-10-2018'
```

If your data is a `string` you will need to define it as a `datetime` object first.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following line:

```
print("Time: ", row[0])
```

To:

```
print("Time: ", row[0].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am getting a error as follow: line 46, in getmyRows
    print("Time: ", row[0].strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'